Downloading lyrics using rgenius
I'm trying to use rgenius to download a bunch of song lyrics like this

library(rgenius)
Sys.setenv(GENIUS_API_TOKEN = 'TOKEN_HERE')

artists=search_genius_artist(artist_name = 'Arctic Monkeys')

artists_id=artists$id

lyrics=get_discography_lyrics(artists_id)

I have a vector with a bunch of artists, but take this just for example.
The problem is that this gives me this error
Error en get_genius_song_lyrics(discography$id[index], output = "text", : 
  task 8 failed - "ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error in `if_else()`:
! `false` must be a vector, not `NULL`."


